# Use ansible to remove all packages associated with a repository

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt, repository

I use the ansible [apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_repository_module.html) module to add and remove Ubuntu repositories. Sometimes, I find it necessary to switch from one repository to an alternate one. And I'd like to have all packages from the old repository removed before adding the new repository and installing the package. Currently, I explicitly use the apt module to remove the package beforehand. Obviously, this incurs unnecessary/repeated work if the same playbook is applied twice.

My question is:

*Is it possible to use ansible to remove all existing packages installed from a given repository (if the repository exists on the target machine)?*

(This is with ansible 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 22.04).

I searched around and only found this (unimplemented) [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58386) for

> additional option of the module like distribution with options:
>
> ```
> keep_all (default for backcompatibility)
> remove_other
> ```
>
> or additional state like 'present_and_remove_other_distribution'.
>
> This additional option should match all present repos using the the
> repo string, match all present repos with exactly the same repo name
> except the distribution

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it possible to use ansible to remove all existing packages installed from a given repository (if the repository exists on the target machine)?*

Yes, of course. Since it seem the requested functionality isn't available within the native OS package manager yet, you will need to use the `shell` instead of the Ansible module for the package manager. Furthermore it will be necessary to have `aptitude` installed.

```yaml
- name: Make sure prerequisites are resolved
  apt:
    name: aptitude
    state: present

- name: Gather list of packages from a specific repository
  shell:
    cmd: aptitude search '~O"{{ REPOSITORY }}" ~i'
  changed_when: false
  register: package_list
```

You need to have a look into the result set and the data structure to address the next step (which I haven't done yet and also not tested). It might be necessary to do some [data manipulation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html).

```yaml
- name: Make sure packages become removed
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}" # or use "{{ package_list }}" directly without loop
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ package_list }}"
```

**Further Q&A**

- [How can I uninstall all packages from one Debian source?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401605/266568)
- [How to delete all non-free or contrib packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458176/266568)
- [What are the apt commands for purging all packages from a specific repository only, and removing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588082/266568)

**Further Documentation**

- [`apt` module – Manages apt-packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html)
- [`package` module – Generic OS package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html)